# Deleting mail in queue before fixing magento cron.php issue

Tags: php, cron, magento-1.9

Magento 1.9.2.2

Since upgrading, the order confirmation emails are not being sent. Aware that Magento switched to queuing email and running of the cron, I checked the error log and found the issue. Every 5 mins it says:

```
Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons  in /home/(SITE NAME)/public_html/cron.php on line 66
Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons  in /home/(SITE NAME)/public_html/cron.php on line 67
```

I can ask my host to adjust the server so that it executes. However, the cron hasn't been working for 3-4 weeks and I'm concerned that when it's fixed, Magento will suddenly send dozens of emails that have been queued up for weeks since the issue arose. We don't want to send these emails.

Is there a way to check and/or delete all emails in the queue before the problem is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This will be help ;)
[Sending Emails by Queue in Magento 1.9.1](http://www.aschroder.com/2015/01/sending-emails-by-queue-in-magento-1-9-1/)
The author discripe the 2 new tabels in the database. My opinion look at the data stored in this table and just clear the table content.

This should delete all mails in queue.

Edit: i forget to say, it seam that you can define a maximum number of mails that are going out per cron run, so dont panic about a burning mail server.